# ¿Cómo puedo poner en un div un background de un color y en el de alado una imagen?

Tags: html, css

estoy tratando de colocar dos div uno a lado del otro, el del lado izquierdo he colocado una imagen con efecto scroll, y en el div del lado derecho me gustaria colocar información, sin embargo la imagen de el lazo izquierdo me ocupa ambos div, he tratado de colocar una imagen de color blanco, sin embargo al momento de querer cambiarle el alto se modifica mucho el tamaño, creo que seria una mejor practica solo colocarle un background de color blanco para que el texto resalte, pero no sé como, o si me pudieran dar una idea o si me hace falta algo, se los gradeceria mucho.

Adjunto mis códigos

Código HTML:

```
 <div class="reviews-area">
            <div class="row no-gutters">
                <div class="col-lg-6 work-right-text d-flex align-items-center ">
                    <div class="px-5 py-5 py-lg-0">
                        <!-- <h2>working with us</h2>
                        <h5>Web Design, Ready Home, Construction and Co-operate Outstanding Buildings.</h5>
                        <a href="#contact" class="ready-btn scrollto">Contact us</a>-->

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6 py-0 x" ><!--ADENTRO DE ESTE DIV TAMBIEN TRATE DE COLOCAR EL BACKGROUND PERO YA NO SE MOSTRABA NADA style="background-color: white;"-->
                    <img src="assets/img/iso/white.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid img-iso">
                    <div class="text">
                        <h2>
                            ¿Qué es la norma de calidad?
                        </h2>
                        <p>
                            ISO 9001 es el estándar internacional que especifica los requisitos para un sistema de gestión de calidad (SGC). Las organizaciones utilizan este estándar para demostrar la capacidad de proporcionar productos y servicios que cumplan con los requisitos
                            reglamentarios y de los clientes de manera consistente satisfaciendo sus necesidades y expectativas.
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            ISO 9001: 2015 se aplica a cualquier organización, independientemente de su tamaño o industria. Esta norma se basa en el Anexo SL, la nueva estructura de alto nivel (HLS) que aporta un marco común a todas las normas del sistema de gestión. Esto ayuda
                            a alinear los diferentes estándares del sistema de gestión, ofrecer subcláusulas coincidentes con la estructura de nivel superior, proporcionar coherencia y aplicar un lenguaje común en todos los estándares.
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
```

Código CSS:

```
.reviews-area {
    background: url(../img/iso/iso2.jpg);
    overflow: hidden;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: top center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
}

.work-left-text {
    background: #3EC1D5 none repeat scroll 0 0;
}

.reviews-area .x {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}

.reviews-area .x .img-iso {
    max-height: 800px;
}

.reviews-area .text {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
}
```

Y algo así se ve en una pantalla de 1920 px, pero en la 320 también se ve mal :
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como pueden ver es muy poca información para un texto tan pequeño, por eso le quiero cambiar el alto, pero se modifica el ancho también =(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes que encerrar dos divs, uno para la imagen y otro para los textos dentro de un div padre y despues si modificar su contenido con CSS, seria algo asi.

```
<div class="contenedor">

   <div class="imagen">
      <img src="" alt="">
   </div>

   <div class="textos">
      <h1></h1>
      <p></p>
   </div>

</div>
```

El div padre en este caso con la clase "contenedor" permitira por medio de flexbox dividir  su ancho total en 50% y 50% y poner la imagen en un div a la izq y los textos en un div a la derecha.

Revisa tu codigo html y veras que solo tienes un div para agrupar la imagen y los textos a la vez.

Y sino tambien intentalo con display: Grid; es otra forma, pero de igual manera tu codigo html no esta bien estructurado, hay esta tu problema.

Comment: Tambien veo que tienes un manojo de codigo html y css para algo tan simple y eso es porque te estas complicando muchisimo con frameworks, al parecer creo estas usando bootstrap, Mi mejor sugerencia es que primero hagas eso simple en CSS puro y ya entenderas mejor como manipular css con frameworks.